# white border on html email in ios

Tags: html, ios, css, html-email

We did html email with dark backgrounds, all is perfect except thin white borders in ios. It has strange behavior of appearance: the bordera appears only in original size, when we zoom screen only horizontal one stays. Some ideas how we can fix it? Screenshots and code snippet are below
https://postimg.org/image/6l32f0cbl/
https://postimg.org/image/rw0mj9ug1/

```
<table style="width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse;"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td style="width:200px; border-collapse: inherit; background-color: #000;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"><img src="http://static.beeline.kz/pics/VIP/bundle.png"></td>
<td style="width:200px; border-collapse: inherit; background-color: #000;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"><img src="http://static.beeline.kz/pics/VIP/call.png"></td>
<td style="width:200px; border-collapse: inherit; background-color: #000;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"><img src="http://static.beeline.kz/pics/VIP/delivery.png"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:200px; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #000;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><div style="font-size:12px; font-family: Arial,Helvetica, Sans-serif; font-weight: bold; line-height: 25px; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;">Большие пакеты минут<br>и Интернет трафика,<br>для звонков по Казахстану<br>и в роуминге</div></td>
<td style="width:200px; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #000;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><div style="font-size:12px; font-family: Arial,Helvetica, Sans-serif; font-weight: bold; line-height: 25px; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;">Приоритет в Call-center,<br>Офисах продаж<br>и обслуживани</div></td>
<td style="width:200px; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #000;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><div style="font-size:12px; font-family: Arial,Helvetica, Sans-serif; font-weight: bold; line-height: 25px; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;">Доставка купленного<br>номера в любую<br>точку Казахстана</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens when you apply background color to two or more table cells individually. To solve it add background-color to parent table.

Found [here](http://www.informz.com/blog/template-design/quick-tip-removing-hairline-borders-in-html-emails-on-iphone-ipad/).

```html
<table style="width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #000;"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td style="width:200px; border-collapse: inherit;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"><img src="http://static.beeline.kz/pics/VIP/bundle.png"></td>
<td style="width:200px; border-collapse: inherit;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"><img src="http://static.beeline.kz/pics/VIP/call.png"></td>
<td style="width:200px; border-collapse: inherit;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"><img src="http://static.beeline.kz/pics/VIP/delivery.png"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:200px; border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><div style="font-size:12px; font-family: Arial,Helvetica, Sans-serif; font-weight: bold; line-height: 25px; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;">Большие пакеты минут<br>и Интернет трафика,<br>для звонков по Казахстану<br>и в роуминге</div></td>
<td style="width:200px; border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><div style="font-size:12px; font-family: Arial,Helvetica, Sans-serif; font-weight: bold; line-height: 25px; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;">Приоритет в Call-center,<br>Офисах продаж<br>и обслуживани</div></td>
<td style="width:200px; border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><div style="font-size:12px; font-family: Arial,Helvetica, Sans-serif; font-weight: bold; line-height: 25px; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;">Доставка купленного<br>номера в любую<br>точку Казахстана</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I had the same Problem recently. This fixed it for me too! Great answer!